# Is Q-Learning Algorithm's implementation recursive?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to implement the Q-Learning. The general algorithm from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning#Algorithm) is as below

[image]

In the statement

[image]

I just don't get it that should i implement the above statement of the original pseudo-code **recursively** for all next states which current state/action can lead us to and max it every time

OR just **choose the maximum value of the next state with current action** from the Action-State Q-Value table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the formula says is that on step `t+1` you update the state-action value by using the state-action value from step `t` and the maximum of values over all the actions for the current state.

Comment: Note that you are actually maximizing over actions applied to the state s_(t+1), so I would probably describe this as maximum of values over all the actions for the _next_ state

Comment: I call `t+1` the current state, because this is the one that was reached upon receiving the reward.